# strtok() and segmentation fault

Tags: c

I have a case, when I type `"1111:2222"` and `"1111:"` or `":2222"`.

When it is `"1111:2222"` - I just print it.

When it is `"1111:"` - I need to set a default value for `b = 0` or for the case, when it is `:2222` for `a = 0`.

Please, how should I handle this case? (I have only one `:` symbol, I handled that condition, don't show it because it is not important)

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char str[80] = "11111:";
   const char s[2] = ":";
   char *token;
   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;


   /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(str, s);
    a = atoi(token);
    printf( " %s\n", a );

    /* get the second token */
    token = strtok(NULL, s); // Here is seg.fault
    if (token != NULL)
        b = atoi(token);
    else    
        b = 0;

    printf( " %s\n", b );
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `printf(" %s\n", a);` -> `printf(" %d\n", a);`. Your compiler should have warned you. The segfault happens in `printf`, not in `strtok`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Daaaaaaaaaaaaaaaamn, stupid mistake! thank you a lot!

Comment: Fault is in this line printf( " %s\n", a ); not where you mentions it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of Segmentation Fault is that integer values are passed to `%s` format for `printf()`. Then `printf()` interprets the numbers as pointers that point at strings.
They are actually not pointers but (in this case small) integers, so readings of strange location happens and this fire Segmentation Fault.

After resolving this by changing `%s` to `%d` or some other formats that take integers, this code will fail to handle `:2222` case and assign `2222` to `a`, not `b` as desired.
This is because `strtok()` drops prefix characters that are contained in the separators.
Therefore, it seems you have to check if the first character is `:` yourself to handle this case.

Comment: Also when I compiled this codeI got a warning that `atom` is not defined. It needs to be included from `stdlib.h`

Comment: @gonczor `atom`? You mean `atoi`?

Comment: @MikeCAT Can you, please, show the solution of checking if the first character `:` ?

Comment: @JustMe If `str` won't contain extra characters such as space characters, just `str[0] == ':'`

Comment: @MikeCAT yes, exactly. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: And if you are goinmg to check the first character is `:` you might as well just check the last character is colon, or that the return from `strchr(input,':')` == `input+strlen(input)-1`. If 2 colons are an error, it is then also easy to detect that with strchr as well, and completely avoid using `strtok` for simple cases like this, because `strtok` is not thread-safe, amongst other issues.